# How to set an action to menubar icon on swipe gesture in swift/SwiftUI

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swift5, swipe-gesture

I'm trying to get a small test app I'm working on to pop up a mini window with a swiftUI view when the menubar icon is swipe down on. Rather than clicking on the button for the window to pop up, a two finger swipe down as if the user pulled down on the icon for the window to show up.
I'm still a bit new to swift but I have the following so far in the AppDelegate.

```
if let button = statusBar.button{
      let iconImage = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name(("iconPic")))
      button.image = iconImage
      button.action = #selector(self.handleOpenPlayerDescriptionWindow(_:))
      button.sendAction(on: .swipe)
//      button.sendAction(on: .leftMouseDown)
    }

 @objc func handleOpenPlayerDescriptionWindow(_ sender: NSMenuItem){
//code to show swiftUI Window 
...
}
```

The pop-up window is simply just a placeholder Text view with an NBA player's game stats.  I've commented out the **sendAction** with '*leftMouseDown*' in the code above because that works perfectly fine, but when I change it to '*swipe*' as a **sendAction**, it does nothing. I've also tried '*beginGesture*', '*endGesture*', and '*gesture*' but all didn't work, the closest success was '*leftMouseDragged*' but not really what I'm going for.

I'm using SwiftUI and not storyboard if maybe that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is limitation of this method, as documented only specific masks are checked by this method, `swipe` is not.

```
> Declaration
> 
> func sendAction(on mask: NSEvent.EventTypeMask) -> Int Discussion
> 
> You use this method during mouse tracking when the mouse button
> changes state, the mouse moves, or if the cell is marked to send its
> action continuously while tracking. Because of this, the only bits
> checked in mask are NSLeftMouseDownMask, NSLeftMouseUpMask,
> NSLeftMouseDraggedMask, and NSPeriodicMask, which are declared in the
> NSEvent class reference.
```

Comment: Ohh thats really unfortunate. There is a mac app called Unclutter that has a similiar functionality as it allows swiping down anywhere on the menubar to drop down the app's view. Any chance something like that can be possible at least? rather than specificaly on the icon, the entire menubar being swipe down-able to reveal an app view or simply just a call to action.